# pikaday with moment is not working

Tags: typescript, momentjs, aurelia, systemjs, pikaday

I am trying to use `pikaday` with `moment`, but somehow I can't make it work.

I am trying to use it in a `aurelia` `custom-attribute` as follows:

```
import "moment";
import "pikaday";

...
    self.picker = new Pikaday({
            field: $(this.element)[0]
            , format: "DD.MM.YYYY"
            , onSelect: (date) => {
                console.log(self.picker.getMoment().format('Do MMMM YYYY')); //getMoment() is always null.
            }
        });
```

Despite importing `moment` prior to `pikaday`, it is not working (as advised in other SO questions and GitHub issues), and getMoment() is always null. Even the date is not by default formatted as per the `format`.

I also found that `hasMoment` is always `false` in `pikaday.js`, as it is not set properly in the first block of code (in the source of `pikaday` as can be ssen below):

```
(function (root, factory)
{
    'use strict';

    var moment;
    if (typeof exports === 'object') {
        // CommonJS module
        // Load moment.js as an optional dependency
        try { moment = require('moment'); } catch (e) {}
        module.exports = factory(moment);
    } else if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        // AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
        define(function (req)
        {
            // Load moment.js as an optional dependency
            var id = 'moment';
            try { moment = req(id); } catch (e) {}
            return factory(moment);
        });
    } else {
        root.Pikaday = factory(root.moment);
    }
}(this, function (moment)
{
    'use strict';

    /**
     * feature detection and helper functions
     */
    var hasMoment = typeof moment === 'function', // this is always false as it can't be set in the above block.
.....
```

Which made me think that I might be importing `moment` in a wrong way. Can anyone please help me on this?

**Additional Details:**
My project settings are as follows:

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "isolatedModules": false,
        "jsx": "react",
        "declaration": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "removeComments": true,
        "noLib": false,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": false,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalAsyncFunctions": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": false        
    },
    "filesGlob": [
        "**/*.ts",
        "**/*.tsx",
        "!node_modules/**"
    ],
    "files": [ ],
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "buildOnSave": false,
    "atom": {
        "rewriteTsconfig": false
    }
}
```

I am also using `system.js`:

```
System.config({
  baseURL: "/",
  defaultJSExtensions: true,
  transpiler: "babel",
  babelOptions: {
    "optional": [
      "runtime",
      "optimisation.modules.system"
    ]
  },
  paths: {
    "*": "dist/*",
    "github:*": "jspm_packages/github/*",
    "npm:*": "jspm_packages/npm/*"
  },
  map: {
      ...
  }
})
```

**Workaround**: Inside `main` (aurelia configuration):

```
import moment from "moment"; 
...
    // Register moment on global scope.
    window["moment"] = moment;
...
```

And, yes I know it is ugly, but does the job :)

Comment: do you have moment installed with jspm? `jspm install npm:moment`, actually you don't need to import 'moment' if you don't use it. If you need it `import moment from 'moment'`

Comment: Thank you for replying. In fact I tried both `import moment from 'moment'` and `import "moment"`, but none of them actually served my purpose. And as for using it, `moment` is not being explicitly used in my typescript code. However I am using a calendar control `pikaday`, which looks for `moment` and tries to use it; thus, I need to load it somehow.

**P.S.** Though `import moment from 'moment'` helps in using moment directly in my typescript file.

Answer (score 3):

This probably isn't of much help to you at this point, but this is how I resolved it:

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
import * as Pikaday from 'pikaday';

Pikaday.prototype.toString = function (format: string) {
    return (this._d instanceof Date) ? moment(this._d).format(format || this._o.format) : '';
};
```

Comment: Fwiw, also works in non-typescript es6 as such: `import moment from 'moment'; import Pikaday from 'pikaday'; Pikaday.prototype.toString = function (format) { return (this._d instanceof Date) ? moment(this._d).format(format || this._o.format) : ''; }` Thanks for the fix!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how system js works but you might have to somehow ensure it gets loaded before pikaday and expose it to other modules as global - like jquery and promise polyfils are usually handled.